# I want to make two layouts of Recycler View: the first layout contains the on-progress data, and the second layout contains done data

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-recyclerview, layout

I'm trying to make an android app for personal project about a complain app, i'm using SQL Server, android studio, PHP for the API. My idea is to create a feature where there are 2 layouts, When users upload their complaints, the information will be stored in the first layout and the status will be on-progress, After admin changes the status to "finish/done" the data will be moved to the second layout automatically, with "finish/done" as its status.

I already have the first layout, which contains all the on-progress and finished complaints. I just need to move the finished complaints to the second layout so the on-progress data and finished data don't mix.

i need an advice to make this happen. i appreciate any advice, thanks !